# Prevent eclipse from destroying CSS formatting

Tags: css, eclipse, formatting, el

Eclipse seems to be completely oblivious of EL expressions inside CSS. When I format my stylesheets, this happens:

```css
.tooltip:hover span.info {
  ...
  border-color: #{theme.get('borderTooltip')};
  border-style: solid;
  ...
}
```

turns into

```css
.tooltip:hover span.info {
  ...
  border-color: #{theme.get('borderTooltip' )
}

;
border-style
:

solid
;
...
}
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent this and still use the formatter?

Comment: In other file types I have used `/* @formatter:off */` and `/* @formatter:on */` comments around sections of code that the formatter messes up.   However, that doesn't seem to work with the CSS formatter for me.

Comment: wow, four years later, still broken :) salute to progress

Comment: I'm actually running into issues with `@keyframes` notation per this bug:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442852

Comment: Eclipse users, please ensure to up-vote the bug as linked by @StephenOstermiller

Comment: @kostja five years, eight months, still broken (Oxygen.2 4.7.2). But you know what they say, *"when life gives you bugged free software..."*

Answer (score -3):

Go to the Eclipse preferences `Window` -> `Preferences`. And enter *formatter* into the search box on the upper left. I don't know which plugin performs the formatting in your case maybe you find the right one here and can change its configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use the eclipse formatter. The CSS formatter does not offer any helpful options for my issue.

Comment: @kostja: Are you using eclipse webtools? Maybe you should give [CSS Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csseditor/) a try.

Comment: This answer isn't specific enough to be helpful.